# Autos Window in VS 2010

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2005 and 2008, the Autos Window displayed all the variables on the current line being debugged as well as the three preceding lines and the three lines after the current.

However, in Visual Studio 2010, the Autos Window displays variables on the current line and one line above and below only.

Does anyone know how to get VS2010 to display the variables on the extra lines that have now been 'dropped'?

Comment: Another reason why I'll be boycotting the POC known as VS2010....

Comment: Sorry about that - last time I trust the documentation.  :)  I'm primarily C# and had worked with VB in 2008 - just assumed it carried over and MSDN (I thought) said so.  Looks like a VS2010 bug.